# How to change from wireframe, to solid or rendered shading mode?

Tags: modeling, rendering

[image]

How to change from the transparent mode to the following rendered/smooth mode?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Click one of the little circles in the top right of the 3D viewport - these are the preview modes (Left to right: Wireframe, Solid, Material, Rendered)

[image]

You want solid, I think.

You can also press <kbd>Z</kbd> in the 3D viewport and pick "solid" from the pie menu that appears.

[image]

For more info read the manual page (yes, there is a manual and has lots of useful information).

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/shading.html

Comment: omg thank you so much! This reply is awesome, informative!