# Viewport shading option "shadow" not displaying shadow

Tags: 3d-view, shaders, shadows

I'm trying to get the viewport to render shadows to help visualize depth when working in an orthogrpahic view. I toggle the shadows option in the viewport shading menu, but it seems like the only thing that happens is the objects are shaded a little darker. I've tried messing around with all of the parameters with no success. I've included a screen cap of objects with and without shadows switched on. I'm sure its something simple that I'm overlooking but I haven't been able to figure it out. Thanks! [image: objects without shadows switched on]

[image: objects with shadows on]

I'm looking for it to display hard shadows in the solid viewport shading mode to illustrate depth as seen in this image [image: proper shadow behavior]

here is a screen recording of what happens now when I turn on shadows, and change the shadow options parameters.

[image: shadows malfunction vid]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change from wireframe, to solid or rendered shading mode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/206234/how-to-change-from-wireframe-to-solid-or-rendered-shading-mode)

Comment: @susu unfortunately not, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The option works fine in 2.92. Maybe take a look at the options (little gear icon):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, yeah I'm using 2.91 which is the most recent version I can find. I've also changed the parameters in the shadow options menu with no success. ill update my original question with a recording showing what its doing right now.